# Error: Optimization error [scripts.[contenthash:20].js]: Error: Terser failed for unknown reason

Tags: angular, npm

I have this error when I build my Angular app:

[image: Error description image]

Comment: Can you paste the auth service you have?

Answer (score 3):

check in your angular.json if you are not calling an empty .js file in scripts

Comment: It works for me! Sadly, my project has also commented whole file.

Answer (score 3):

Following up on Gatos reply, I was able to get a successful build after removing

```
"scripts": ["src/assets/js/pay-with-amazon.min.js"],
```

From my build > options in angular.json.

I would start by removing your scripts one by one and attempting a build after each removal to figure out the culprit and then determine how to resolve the issue from there.

Good luck.

Comment: that is work to me after removing js from 'scripts'

Answer (score 0):

making sure you do not have any unused files in "scripts":  in the angular.json should resolve this issue.